# Add to cart, view cart, view item and purchase item in GTM as an array

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am having difficulties to list multiple items that were added or purchased to list them in an array in GTM due to my inability to understand javascript. But I do have the Javascript codes that were used to create variables to collect the information regarding the product name, price, quantity etc. Now for the problem of listing item in an array, "Is it absolutely mandatory to keep them in an array when one particular user adds/views/purchases multiple products while visiting the ecommerce website as GA4 collects the events as individual events and shows in the report? Isn't it enough to send the event parameters with the events (add_to_cart, view_item, purchase etc) to be able to see the detailed report in GA4?". Please suggest what do you think! Thanks in advance!

Tried to get products in an array but failed.